# Accessing a file incrementally in java while it is being dynamically updated?

Tags: java, file-io, random-access

I want to read a file incrementally in java while the file is being modified/written by some other process. So suppose Process "A" is writing/logging a file "X" and another process "B" wants to incrementally read the file "X", say every 1 sec (or even continuously) to find a particular pattern. What's the best way to do this in java? I know I can use RandomAccessFile's 'seek' method but will that interfere with the writing of the file? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Poll the data modified of the file.  Opening it up for reading can prevent other programs from writing to the file at the same time.

Comment: At this point I 'grep' the file for the pattern I'm am searching, so it doesn't interfere with the other process writing on the file. But in doing that I have to read the whole file each time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use Java 7, you could take advantage of the [WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) ... but it doesn't solve having to parse the whole file.

The only thing I can think off is maintaining some kind of "marker" that would indicate the last position you were up to.  The next time you came to read the file, you could skip to this point and read from there (updating the marker when you're done)